# curl from shell script

Tags: http, shell, unix, curl

I am trying to delete few objects using curl. I have a list of ids for the onjects in a file. 
I loop through the list and issue a del like this:

```
bash -x del.sh tempId.log

+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
+ curl -H 'Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA' -X DELETE https://url/id
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]+ read id
```

This is the script

```
   #!/bin/bash
    while read id; do
    curl -H "Authorization:OAuth 00D30000001FxvA%21AQEAQKkcrruykRDNDapigaEdJXOc4SS_D27o686DScK8pU22BeMsgWVsWJ.Nv0DXimx2zBFKYlAUeDnGgokY2pU8m9xMoe73&apv=1&cshc=0000004qUmq0000001FxvA" -X DELETE https:url/$id
    done <$1
```

However, if I run the same curl command on the terminal it works fine !

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a leading `$` on your `id` value in the debug trace that I  DO see in your script. Not sure what to make of that. good luck.

Comment: I have obfuscated the IDS in the debug trace.

Comment: `https:url/` -- what's that `url/` doing there?

Comment: Does it _still_ work fine on the command line? It looks just what it says -- an expired session -- which would mean that the token you're passing in _used_ to work but no longer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Few things, as already pointed by others

1. What is `url`? The needs to be a actual url of a variable `$url` having a value initialized before being used.
2. Be sure, the complete url after parsing leads to the actual one that you need. Do a echo for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble if you have ampersand (&) in the URL. That needs to be escaped within a shell script, but not on the command line.

eg:

```
http://myweb.com/myservlet?asd=1&jkl=2
```

needs to be

```
http://myweb.com/myservlet?asd=1\&jkl=2
```